# mapDispatchToProps action is not a function

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

So I do this in container:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators({fetchMarkers}, dispatch)
  }
}
```

and when props is logged in browser I get:

```
actions: {
    fetchMakers: function() ....
}
```

but when I call `this.props.actions.fetchMarkers(params)` I get the following error:

> Cannot read property 'fetchMarkers' of undefined

This is driving me nuts, Please help!

Edit:

Action:

```
export const fetchMarkers = (payload) => {
  return {
    type: actionTypes.fetchMarkers,
    payload
  }
}
```

Comment: Can we see more, how you connect and where you use it?

Comment: I would say you are importing fetchMarkers incorrectly, because when you bind it like you do, you should be able to execute the action creator with `this.props.actions();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this case:

```
import { fetchMarkers } from 'path_to_makers_action';

....Code of react component....

export default connent(null, { fetchMarkers });
```

And in component you use: `this.props.fetchMarkers()`

Comment: You can attach redux-thunk middleware to your project what would fell all power of async actions.

[https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk)